# Debugging COM object in a foreign process

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, com

My Dll COM object (written in C#) is loaded by a 3rd party process (as a plugin). Is there any why to debug it other then logging?

**UPDATE:**

Just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543895/debugging-into-c-sharp-code-from-other-application), which is the *exact* scenario I was looking for.

Comment: do you have the source code?

Comment: I have the source code for the plugin, yes.

Comment: did you just reported yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attach your Visual Studio debugger to the other process when it is running.
You may have to start Visual Studio as administrator (elevated rights) for this to succeed.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the source code, you can attach the debugger to the process that loads the code and you will be able to step through this.

Answer (score 2):

if you have the source code then you can attach to process using VS:
Tools->Attach to Process
then a form is opening:

[image]
there you choose your 3rd party application and your done!